# How to rewrite this SQL script using JOINS

Tags: sql, join

I have made this SQL script using Cartesian prouct

```
SELECT name
FROM Station, Sale, Fuel
WHERE (Station.id_station=Sale.id_station) AND (Sale.id_fuel=Fuel.id_fuel)
      AND MAX(Fuel.volume)
```

I would like to know how can I make it using JOINs. Basicaly it selects the name of a station which has the largest Fuel tanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that.

```
select top 1 name
from station st
inner join sale sa on sa.id_station = st.id_station
inner join fuel f on f.id_fuel = sa.id_fuel
order by f.volume desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT name
    FROM Station
    INNER JOIN Sale ON Station.id_station=Sale.id_station
    INNER JOIN Fuel ON Sale.id_fuel=Fuel.id_fuel
    WHERE MAX(Fuel.volume)= ?
```

You haven't said what you want from max(Fuel.colume) that is why the ?  is there.